# How to use JTCalendar without Stroybord/Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nscalendar

I didn't get how to use without Storyboard/Xib usage of JTCalendar.
normally any view can add in super view for Ex: [self.view addSubview :SampleView1]
How can I add on my custom View.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JTCalendar/JTCalendar.h"
@interface GitCalendarViewController : UIViewController <JTCalendarDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarMenuView *calendarMenuView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTHorizontalCalendarView *calendarContentView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendarManager *calendarManager;




@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _calendarManager = [JTCalendarManager new];
    _calendarManager.delegate = self;

    [_calendarManager setMenuView:_calendarMenuView];
    [_calendarManager setContentView:_calendarContentView];
    [_calendarManager setDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

how can I add those my subview . Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:_calendarManager];
```

Doesn't work ?  calendarManager is a subclass of wich class ?